# how to remove the top color from an android navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

How can I remove the primary color from the below drawer?
[image: drawer.png]

I tried to remove the header items from the drawer but the above selected color still remains.

Comment: Post the layout file of your Navigation Drawer. That color is been help by a view in there.

Comment: is the sample from android studio, when you create newDrawerActivity

Answer (score 1):

try to set navigation drawer padding Top 20dp/24dp
and create navigation drawer background like this.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:top="20dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

and set navigation drawer file

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:background="@drawable/menu_navigation"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The earlier answer might work too, but it feels that it's too much compared to what you want to achieve. You can just change the navigation view such that it doesn't draw over the statusbar.

In your `activity_main.xml` change the `android:fitsSystemWindows` of the **NavigationView** element to `false`. Doing this will give you the desired result.

*Thus the codeblock will look like this:*

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```